# Should SE blog posts that are about SO show up twice?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, blog

The "yellow box" is currently showing a blog post across the SE network about a new hiring and the launch of SO in Russian, but here on SO (and Meta.SO) it shows up twice, presumably because it's tagged with SO in some way?

[image]

Is this intended behaviour? On other sites it only shows up once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is a bug.

Marked as completed, as we fixed the immediate issue (blog post showing up twice).

We still need to look at the underlying cause.

Comment: Oded, the same issue happened [again](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300731/duplicated-blog-post-showing-on-so-hot-meta-posts-area) yesterday. Was the underlying cause found or not yet?

Comment: @Zanon - should have been. I think this one was operator error.