# Duplicated blog post showing on SO "Hot Meta Posts" area

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, blog

This error is happening [again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296687/should-se-blog-posts-that-are-about-so-show-up-twice):

[image: duplicated]

Comment: The issue was fixed. Not happening today.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, [Oded believes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296687/should-se-blog-posts-that-are-about-so-show-up-twice/296692?noredirect=1#comment228721_296692) that this time was an operator error.

Comment: Ah, thanks for following up.